# Use palette when using FFMpeg overlay

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, image-manipulation

I'm trying to add an overlay to an animated GIF with FFMpeg.

It works, but the quality is pretty dismal. Basically, I'm unable to use the palette that I generate, and that leads to a lot of dither. The main GIF (meaning, not the overlay) is also very low resolution.

I would also like to apply opacity to the watermark (and at one point that worked, too), but that's a plus.

This is what I have:

```
ffmpeg -v error -i image.gif -vf 'palettegen' palette.png -y;
ffmpeg -v error -i image.gif -i watermark.gif -i palette.png -filter_complex '[1:v]scale=80:30, [0:v]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w) - main_h/30:(main_h-overlay_h) - main_h/30, paletteuse' -an image-watermark.gif -y
```

At one point I was able to use the palette for the main GIF, so its quality improved. However, the watermark looked pretty bad. It's pretty obvious that I have to do the overlay, and then the palette, so that the palette include the colors present in the watermark. However, I have no idea how to do that.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate the palette for the same visual content that you wish to encode to GIF.

```
ffmpeg -v error -i image.gif -i watermark.gif -filter_complex  '[1:v]scale=80:30[wm];[0:v][wm]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w) - main_h/30:(main_h-overlay_h) - main_h/30, palettegen' palette.png -y;

ffmpeg -v error -i image.gif -i watermark.gif -i palette.png -filter_complex '[1:v]scale=80:30[wm];[0:v][wm]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w) - main_h/30:(main_h-overlay_h) - main_h/30[vid];[vid][2]paletteuse' -an image-watermark.gif -y
```

(I've kept your existing syntax, although it's preferable to label all input and output pads and not rely on automatic input pickup.)

Comment: Thanks! I actually had added that bit, but the main GIF's quality is still really bad—like pixellated. It almost looks like it got downsampled.

Comment: Try it with fully specified pads.

Comment: For "fully specified pads", you mean this: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad-1?

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. Unfortunately though, the main image still looks pixellated. It's the correct size, but it looks lower quality than the original. I have many other filters working, it's just this one that I can't seem to figure out. :-/